# ngrx not dispatching action in Observable.interval

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've an angular application using ngrx and I want to send an action every x seconds, so I did this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = Observable.interval(1000)
      .do(() => this.store.dispatch(new LoadDataAction()))
      .subscribe();
  }
```

So this should be sending an action every second. I'm ussing ngrx/effects to intercept this action and call a service, but it only works the first time. It's like my subscription is finished after the first call.

If I substitute the action call for the service call it all works.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my @Effects

```
@Effect()
  data$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_DATA_ACTION)
    .do(() => console.log('LoadDataEffectService'))
    .switchMap(() => this.service.getData())
    .do(data => new DataLoadedAction(data));
```

EDIT.

Ok, I got the problem, the last do has to be map.

Comment: what does your service actualy do? does it send request to server? are you sure your service is not throwing any error? because if you get error thrown by service and you don't catch that error in your effects then your effects will get unsubscribed frmo actions and no further actions will be handled by effects.

Comment: my service is working fine, it actually returns some mock data; could @effects be detecting that the data returned is actually always the same and then stopped the processing?

Comment: no no, effects don't care about data returned, they operate on actions only. I would say that you have an error thrown somewhere in your service or in your DataLoadedAction or reducer that handled DataLoadedAction. i would check that twice if i were you. or you can try to put catch block in your effects. something like `.catch((err) => { return Observable.of(new DateLoadedFailureAction(err))});` right after your `do` part

Comment: I already put the catch in effects and I get nothing :(
the thing is that not even the first do, that logs out some message, is executed

Comment: your `.do` and `.catch` on it should be within `switchMap`, not outside.

Comment: the way you have it your service returns data which in turns makes your observable in effects return service response and not Action and that is an error and detaches effects.

Comment: this is my service ```getData(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('service');
    return Observable.of(DATA_MOCK);
  }```
so it returns an Observable

Comment: yes but not `Observable<Action>`, which is a signature of your effects and you get a cast error:). try  to put your `do` and `catch` within `switchMap`. that should work.

Comment: do doesn't dispactch action use map instead